# How do I update CentOS 6.3 to 6.10?

Tags: centos6

I'm getting yum SSL connection error when updating CentOS 6.3 to 6.10 today. Is it possible to run `yum update` to update CentOS 6.3?

Comment: CentOS 6 reached end of life on November 30th, 2020. Any package repositories have since been taken off line and archived. So if you remain insistent on continuing with this upgrade (which I highly advise against because CentOS 6 is no longer maintained and the update to 6.10 will still contain many bugs and vulnerabilities that will never be patched), you will need to locate an archived repository and mirror it yourself and proceed that way. Recommend you re-install with CentOS 7, or preferably, CentOS 8.

Comment: CentOS 7 is preferable over CentOS 8. CentOS 8 reaches its end of life in two weeks, while 7 is supported for 2 more years.

Answer (score 1):

No, continuing to use CentOS 6 is not a responsible thing to do. It is [end of life](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product) and has security vulnerabilities. And perhaps its PKI no longer being maintained is contributing to your TLS problems.

Reinstall a newer version of RHEL or a rebuild. RHEL, Rocky, Alma, Oracle EL. CentOS is now CentOS Stream, which as a beta of RHEL might not be exactly what you want, but is an option.